# Can't access child object in javascript, nevertheless I see it

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a problem with a javascript object returned from a mongo db, if I console.log the parent object, I see the child object, if console.log or use the child object, I get undefined

```
const templateResponse = await this.dbService.findbyCode(req);  // <= here I get the parent object

console.log('EmailService -> getEmailCOntent -> templateResponse', templateResponse); 

if (templateResponse) {
console.log('EmailService -> getEmailCOntent -> templateResponse6666', templateResponse.email);
}
```

---

```
EmailService -> sendMails -> emailContent
```

here I console.log parent and I see child email object:

```
{ _id: 5f5421eaa9248b90c815d80b,
  email:
   { to: 'email@mail.com',
     cc: '',
     bcc: '',
     subject: 'testttt',
     body: 'this is a test',
     from: 'no-reply@test.com' },
  code: 'REQUESTOREMAILNOACCESS',
  name: '',
  description: '',
  __v: 0
 }
```

if I try to console.log child object I get undefined, I also tried `templateResponse['email']`

```
EmailService -> getEmailCOntent -> templateResponse.email 
undefined
```

Comment: What does `findByCode` do?  Is it possible that is returning a cursor and not a simple object?

Answer (score 0):

So I i fixed the problem by simply adding .lean() at the end of my mongo find function.